# Angular directive with two input elements: can't get $watch to work on ng-model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to write an Angular directive which has a template containing two input fields (eventually this will be a Date and Time picker) and can't get $watch to fire on either of the input value changes. I have as a test:

HTML

```
<tw-input-test label="Test" ng-model="myModel.value"></tw-input-test>
```

Angular

```
app.directive("twInputTest", function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope:{ label:'=' },
        templateUrl:"templates/tw-input-test.html",
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            scope.twone=42;
            scope.twtwo=27;
            scope.updateTest=function(){
                scope.label= scope.twone.toString()+"-"+scope.twtwo.toString();
            }
            scope.$watch(scope.twone,scope.updateTest, true);
            scope.$watch('scope.twtwo',scope.updateTest, true);
        }
    };
});
```

Template

```
<div class="form-item">
    <span>{{label}}</span>
    <input type='number' style="width:80px" ng-model="twone">
    <input type='number' style="width:80px" ng-model="twtwo">
</div>
```

I can see the values of scope.twone, scope.twtwo change when the input boxes are altered (using Chrome dev tools), but updateTest() is only called when the link function is initially called.

Comment: Did you try to do so using `controller: function(...) { .. }` instead of doing this on `link`?

Comment: Maybe you need to add name for input if you want the ng-model to work

Comment: `scope.$watch('twtwo', ...`